# Sanitise data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to sanitize data in cakephp but i am facing a problem. i have a form with a  date field . When i tried to sanities all the data the date looses it's mysql format and is stored in the db as a rubbish data(1970-01-01) but if i remove the sanitize it works fine

i tried the following

```
 function beforeSave() 
    {
       $this->data = Sanitize::clean($this->data);
       return true;
    }
```

i also tried this and this works but it defeats the purpose

```
function beforeSave() 
{

   $date = $this->data['Cabinet']['date_of_inspection'];        
   $this->data = Sanitize::clean($this->data);
   $this->data['Cabinet']['date_of_inspection'] = $date;
   return true;
}
```

what is the way out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->data = Sanitize::clean($this->data, array('encode' => false)` solved the problem.  i agree with what Jamal Aziz/Cakephp says

Answer (score 7):

From [CakePHP Manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1183/Data-Sanitizationoutput/display.) :

> CakePHP already protects you against
>   SQL Injection if you use CakePHP's ORM
>   methods (such as find() and save())
>   and proper array notation (ie.
>   array('field' => $value)) instead of
>   raw SQL. For sanitization against XSS
>   its generally better to save raw HTML
>   in database without modification and
>   sanitize at the time of
>   output/display.output/display.

Comment: The link no longer seems to work. Do you have an updated link? Does this advice still apply for current versions of Cake?

Comment: Updated document: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html